# ANTLR - Distinguish 'IS NOT NULL' from 'IS NULL'

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr3

How can I differentiate '**IS NOT NULL**' from '**IS NULL**'?

'IS' and 'IS NOT' are defined in a parser rule, and 'NULL' in another rule, and the second follows the first.

What happens is that when I write 'IS NULL', the Parser is excepting 'IS NOT NULL' because **both second words begin with 'N'**.

How can I distinguish both?

---

Grammar File

```
query
    :   expr EOF -> ^(QUERY expr)   
    ;

expr
    :   logical_expr
    ;

logical_expr
    :   equality_expr (logical_op^ equality_expr)*
    ;

equality_expr
    :   ID equality_op atom     -> ^(equality_op ID atom)
    ;

atom
    :   ID
    ;

equality_op
    :   '='
    |   '!='
    |   'IN'
    |   'NOT IN'
    |   'IS'
    |   'IS NOT'
    ;

logical_op
    :   'AND'
    |   'OR'
    ;

Number
    :   Int ('.' Digit*)?
    ;

ID
    :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '.' | '-' | Digit)* 
    ;

...
```

Comment: Surely you'd tokenize the input first, in which case the fact that `NOT` and `NULL` begin with the same character won't be an issue?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with 'tokenize the input first'? Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Comment: I edited my Question with the Grammar File. Is not what I am doing?

Comment: @BartKiers, I've post it moments ago.

Comment: You may want to try `equality_op ... |   'IS' ( 'NOT' )? ;`

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, now 'IS NOT NULL' is working, but when I write 'IS NULL' it gives me an error on the word 'NULL' : 'mismatched character 'N' expecting 'I''

Comment: Hmm - odd. Hopefully an actual ANTLR expert will come along.

Comment: That's because I have the 'IN' and 'NOT IN'. And it is confusing the 'NOT' of both operations...!

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion with (NOT) IN as well? I noticed something else: You have 'NOT IN' and 'IS NOT'. I don't think that's right - you want 'NOT' 'IN' and 'IS' 'NOT' - you don't want the amount of white space to be significant.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, I'v tried with 'IS' ('NOT')? and ('NOT')? 'IN', but the negatives forms are not working. And yes, I want 'NOT IN' and 'IS NOT' because the next word has another meaning... These are the names of the possible operations.

Comment: Don't use whitespace in your tokens. Use 'IS' 'NOT' and 'NOT' 'IN'.